# Медиа запросы и HTML

Tags: html5, css3, media-queries

Делаю горизонтальное меню, возникла мысль чтобы при отражении на мобильных устройства вместо текста появлялась маленькая картинка (Font Awesome - если вкурсе).

Хочу узнать можно ли с помощью HTML & CSS решить данную проблему? То есть на компьютере "О нас/Портфолио/Контакты/Блог", а на мобильном значки?

Comment: Можно! Вы даже тег правильно указали, который вам поможет

Comment: А как именно это реализовать? А то я что то торможу.Чтобы не быть голословным, вот разметка.<nav>
             <ul class="menu">
                 <li>About me</li>
                    <li>For U</li>
                    <li>Portfolio</li>
                    <li>Blog</li>
                </ul> 
            </nav>   Нужно чтобы на мобильнике были картинки,но как

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться готовыми фреймворками? Bootstrap, например, все сам делает: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: Потому что учусь!

Comment: @Strowitzki добавьте пример Вашего кода в текст вопроса

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так. В каждый пункт меню размещаем два блока: для десктопа и для мобильных.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <span class="desktop-menu-item">About me</span>
      <span class="mobile-menu-item">☺</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="desktop-menu-item">For U</span>
      <span class="mobile-menu-item"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="desktop-menu-item">Blog</span>
      <span class="mobile-menu-item">✉</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

В CSS показываем/скрываем нужные блоки, в зависимости от того, на мобильном девайсе мы или нет.

```
.mobile-menu-item {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {

.mobile-menu-item {
  display: initial;
}

.desktop-menu-item {
  display: none;
}

}
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/y3hsmvr7/